# No automatic update for Visual Studio 2015 to update 1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 in the community version.

Today I saw that since some days there is an update to Version "Update 1". I was wondering, that my windows or visual stuido did not tell me that there is a update available.

Is this normal in VS, do I always have to keep it up to date by downloading the newest installer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you didn't see it is that VS has two actions. The first is that we publish a VSUpdate for people to find and download directly. After a period of time, then we publish an atom feed file that VS will download and use to notify you. What you were seeing is that we made VSU1 available on Nov 30th, but we didn't publish the atom feed file until Dec 14th. (And even then, VS only fetches the updated atom feed file once every 24 hours, so it could have been Dec 15th when your VS would have gotten the file that caused the notification).

Answer (score 3):

Keeping up-to-date manually by keeping an eye on tech blogs is faster than waiting for Visual Studio to inform you.

You can find the update on MSDN and download it there, or use the link in this [Microsoft Blog post on the release of VS2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) to download it.

**Update:**

This morning my Visual Studio Professional 2015 suddenly drew a yellow box around the Notification Center icon, and upon clicking it told me that '"Visual Studio 2015 Update 1" is available'.

[image: Notification Center VS2015]